# Query SQL Server from Excel with parameters

Tags: sql, excel, vba, parameters, import

What I'm trying to do is use a pull information from SQL server into an excel spreadsheet using a query with parameters.

I've been able to query the database from excel but have not been able to figure out how to add parameters.

I need the parameter to be taken from a cell in the sheet.

```
Sub DataExtract()

Dim cnPubs As ADODB.Connection
Set cnPubs = New ADODB.Connection
Dim strConn As String
strConn = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;"
strConn = strConn & "DATA SOURCE= MyServer ;INITIAL CATALOG = MyDatabase ;"
strConn = strConn & " INTEGRATED SECURITY=sspi;"
cnPubs.Open strConn
Dim rsPubs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rsPubs = New ADODB.Recordset
With rsPubs

.ActiveConnection = cnPubs

.Open "SELECT * FROM [MyTable] WHERE ColA = ?"

Sheet1.Range("B12").CopyFromRecordset rsPubs

.Close
End With
cnPubs.Close
Set rsPubs = Nothing
Set cnPubs = Nothing
End Sub
```

any help on how I could simply have the question mark in the query reference a cell in the sheet would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested:

```
Sub DataExtract()

Dim cmd as ADODB.Command, param as Object, val
Dim cnPubs As ADODB.Connection
Dim rsPubs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim strConn As String

    Set cnPubs = New ADODB.Connection

    strConn = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;"
    strConn = strConn & "DATA SOURCE= MyServer ;INITIAL CATALOG = MyDatabase ;"
    strConn = strConn & " INTEGRATED SECURITY=sspi;"
    cnPubs.Open strConn

    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [MyTable] WHERE ColA = ?"
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdText


    val = Sheet1.Range("A1").Value 'query value to be used
    'create and add the parameter
    Set param = cmd.CreateParameter("", adVariant, adParamInput, 0, val)
    cmd.parameters.Append param

    Set cmd.ActiveConnection = cnPubs

    Set rsPubs = cmd.Execute()

    Sheet1.Range("B12").CopyFromRecordset rsPubs

End Sub
```

Comment: I use that successfully with Oracle (not an Access user) - not familiar with SQL server. I do see plenty of examples using `?`  with SQL Server though.

Comment: yeah, I guess the ADO driver figures it out. The naming comes in if you want to define your parameters in any order. I'm surprised you haven't used Access though

Comment: @Brad - I wouldn't say I've "never" used Access, but we're more of an Oracle shop here.

Comment: Works perfectly! I realise how simple a question it is but i just could not wrap my head around it until now. Thanks!